# Pytesseract missing lines

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract and cv2 in my project and want to read the text from the following image (after cv2 processing):
[image]
The text seems to be clearly visible and pytesseract is returning the lines correctly but is missing "Da-Dumm" and "Ploink".

```
# load the image 
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 1)

# store grayscale image as a temp file to apply OCR
filename = "Screens/{}.png".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)

# load the image as a PIL/Pillow image, apply OCR, and then delete the temporary file
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename),lang="deu")
```

Comment: Which version of tesseract is being used ? and have you tried with config setting in pytesseract like page segmentation mode and OEM etc